# Jquery Selected Rows Value

Tags: datatable, rows

I have a datatable. I want to retrieve the ID values of the rows that are selected.
How can I do that.
My codes:

```js
var DatatableRecordSelectionDemo = function () {

            var demo = function () {
                var url = '/Data/default.json';
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    var datatable = $('.m_datatable').mDatatable({
                        data: {
                            type: "local",
                            source: data,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            saveState: {
                                cookie: true,
                                webstorage: true
                            },
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },

                        // layout definition
                        layout: {
                            theme: 'default', // datatable theme
                            "class": '', // custom wrapper class
                            scroll: false, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
                            height: 550, // datatable's body's fixed height
                            footer: false // display/hide footer
                        },

                        // column sorting
                        sortable: true,

                        pagination: true,

                        // columns definition
                        columns: [{
                            field: "RecordID",
                            title: "#",
                            sortable: false, // disable sort for this column
                            width: 40,
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            selector: { class: 'm-checkbox--solid m-checkbox--brand' }
                        }, {
                            field: "OrderID",
                            title: "Numara",
                            // sortable: 'asc', // default sort
                            filterable: true, // disable or enable filtering
                            // basic templating support for column rendering,
                            template: '{{OrderID}} - {{ShipCountry}}'
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            title: "Adı"
                        }, {
                            field: "Status",
                            title: "Durumu",
                            // callback function support for column rendering
                            template: function (row) {
                                var status = {
                                    true: { 'title': 'Aktif', 'class': ' m-badge--success' },
                                    false: { 'title': 'Pasif', 'class': ' m-badge--danger' }
                                };
                                return '<span class="m-badge ' + status[row.Status].class + ' m-badge--wide">' + status[row.Status].title + '</span>';
                            }
                        }, {
                            field: "Actions",
                            title: "İşlem",
                            width: 100,
                            sortable: false,
                            overflow: 'visible',
                            template: function (row) {
                                var tblName = String(row.ShipName).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                                var tblid = String(row.RecordID);
                                return '\
      <a href="#" onclick="Modalac('+ tblid + ',\'' + tblName + '\',' + row.Status + ')" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Düzenle">\
       <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
      </a>\
      <a href="#" onclick="Sil('+ tblid + ',\'' + tblName + '\')" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Sil">\
       <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
      </a>\
     ';
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                    var query = datatable.getDataSourceQuery();

                    $('#m_form_search').on('keyup', function (e) {
                        // shortcode to datatable.getDataSourceParam('query');
                        var query = datatable.getDataSourceQuery();
                        query.generalSearch = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                        // shortcode to datatable.setDataSourceParam('query', query);
                        datatable.setDataSourceQuery(query);
                        datatable.load();
                    }).val(query.generalSearch);
                    $('#m_form_status').on('change', function () {
                        // shortcode to datatable.getDataSourceParam('query');
                        var query = datatable.getDataSourceQuery();
                        query.Status = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                        // shortcode to datatable.setDataSourceParam('query', query);
                        datatable.setDataSourceQuery(query);
                        datatable.load();
                    }).val(typeof query.Status !== 'undefined' ? query.Status : '');

                    $('#m_form_status').selectpicker();

                    // on checkbox checked event
                    $('.m_datatable').on('m-datatable--on-check', function (e, args) {
                            var count = datatable.setSelectedRecords().getSelectedRecords().length;
                            $('#m_datatable_selected_number').html(count);
                            if (count > 0) {
                                $('#m_datatable_group_action_form').collapse('show');
                            }
                        })
                        .on('m-datatable--on-uncheck m-datatable--on-layout-updated', function (e, args) {
                            var count = datatable.setSelectedRecords().getSelectedRecords().length;
                            $('#m_datatable_selected_number').html(count);
                            if (count === 0) {
                                $('#m_datatable_group_action_form').collapse('hide');
                            }
                        });
                    $('.m_datatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (){
                        var id = this.RecordID;
                        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
                        if (index === -1) 
                        {
                            selected.push(id);
                        } else 
                        {
                            selected.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                    });
                });
            };

            return {
                // public functions
                init: function () {
                    demo();
                }
            };
        }();
        
         var TopluIslem = function () {
            var datatable = $('.m_datatable').mDatatable();
            var dataArr = [];
            $.each($(".m_datatable tr.selected"),function(){
                dataArr.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());    
            });
            console.log(dataArr);
            alert(rowCount);

           
        };
         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            DatatableRecordSelectionDemo.init();
        });
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger islem_yap" onclick="TopluIslem()">İşlem Yap</a>
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

https://jsfiddle.net/4famyw1a/

Comment: What library is **`mDatatable`** ...?

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469

to buy, I did not review much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

```
var secilenler = [];
$('.m_datatable').on('m-datatable--on-check', function(e, args) {
                    secilenler.push(args.toString());
                }).on('m-datatable--on-uncheck', function (e, args) {
                    var i = secilenler.indexOf(args.toString());
                    if(i !== -1) {
                        secilenler.splice(i, 1);
                    }

                });
```